# Django tests manage.py

Tags: python, django, testing, manage.py

To run my Django's tests, I was using the manage.py file.
But I decided to create my own file runtests.py.

As specified in the Django's [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/), the manage.py file will execute all methods whose name is starting like "test" and whose class inherits TestCase !

My aim is to use this searching method to display all possible tests (not running them).
So do you know where I could get this "searching method" ?

Thank you !

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/ says "You can also provide a path to a directory to discover tests below that directory" $ ./manage.py test animals/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "test discovery", and you don't need to do it manually.

If you want to write a standalone script that runs your tests, you can simply invoke Django's test runner manually from Python code after configuring. The process for this is:

```
# First you need settings.
# You can do this by setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'path.to.your.settings')

# Or you can do it manually:
SETTINGS_DICT = {
    # Put all the settings you'll need in here...
}
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(**SETTINGS_DICT)

import django
django.setup()

import sys

# Now you can run tests:
from django.test.utils import get_runner
TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
test_runner = TestRunner(verbosity=2, interactive=True)
failures = test_runner.run_tests(
    ['test_module_to_look_in']
)
sys.exit(bool(failures))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would actually only display all test cases of my app..

Comment: Django's test discovery uses the Python unittest module's test discovery and loading code. You can read through how Django does it here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/02114f9c49a1cad3f7fe86fe36fcda18632ffb7e/django/test/runner.py#L396